# HTML5 video frame capture to bitmap

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-canvas

I got this script:

```
function capture(video, scaleFactor) {
    if(scaleFactor == null){
        scaleFactor = 1;
    }
    var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
    var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width  = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);


    return canvas;
} 


function shoot(){
    var video  = document.getElementById(videoId);
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var canvas = capture(video, scaleFactor);
    canvas.onclick = function(){
        window.open(this.toDataURL());
    };
    snapshots.unshift(canvas);
    output.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i=0; i<1; i++){
        output.appendChild(snapshots[i]);
    }

}
```

What I want to do is export the snapshot to a bitmap image. I read that I could use this line:

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

But I don't know where to add it.

Any ideas?

Comment: _When_ do you want to export the snapshot as a bitmap?  Its not clear how you want this to work - when `shoot` is called?  When the canvas is clicked?  Some other condition?  While we're at it, `image/jpeg` is not a bitmap type - which do you want?

Comment: It's called when the user clicks a button.

Comment: What I want is to be able to save the image as a jpeg or png with a right click when the image is generated.

Answer (score 2):

ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
canvas.toDataURL(...)

toDataURL will return you a string which is usually base64 encoded image (file) content. You can display it in image tag by  < img src="the string"/>. Or you can use javascript to do whatever you want...

Comment: Can you verify that the code can capture everything but video?

Comment: I'm kind of a noob on this canvas concept. I don't understand that.

Comment: Can you pass a different object ( other than video ) to see if the code works. The code should work for text, images...

Comment: Then I don't have an answer for you. I don't know how html5 standard say ( does it exist? ) about it. It is up to the browser now....  ( try to pause the video to see if it helps )

Comment: Doesn't work. I'll keep trying to improv a solution. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it to window.open

```
canvas.onclick = function () {
    window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
};
```

Full Example : http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Comment: Forgot to mention that you need to run this under a server. See here : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/integrating/

Comment: Edited the answer with a link. Check that.